# How to change hasMany(), belongsTo() or any relationship return data in the function setting it?

Tags: php, function, laravel, laravel-5, relationships

Is it possible to change the data `hasMany()` and other relationship functions in Laravel return in the same function where you're calling the relationship?

The problem is that in order for all of it to work you need to return the relationship, and returning anything automatically ends the function.

Example:

```
function problems() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Problem'); // the function ends at this line
    $this->problem = $this->problems->name; // so this one never executes
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for here. Why are you needing to set the `$problem` property in this method?

Comment: @Devon I need to reformat it. If I select a single column instead of the hole object using the relationship it returns an associative array with a single record, the selected column, and saves that array as a property of the object. 
I want it to save just the value, not the whole array
`function problem() {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Problem')->select('name');
      $this->problem = $this->problem["name"];`
That's actually what I want, sorry for not being clear in the question.

Comment: That isn't how it works.  Accessing  the property `$problems` (because of the magic method) looks for the problems() method to return a relationship.  You don't set the property `$problems`.

Comment: @Devon Oh, I see, it makes sense. I wrongly thought that the method automatically sets the property despite me not declaring it. Thanks :)

Comment: If you want the `$problem` property to be the name, use a mutator like `getProblemAttribute()`, but to avoid confusion with the relationship, I'd recommend using something like `$problem_name` instead of `$problem`.